# Parse an Array from JSON where each field key is a number

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

What I essentially need to do is, given a json like

```
{
  "1" : "a",
  "7" : "something"
  "3" : {
      "1" : "blah"
  }
}
```

Convert these to an array (say x).

```
x[1] = "a"
x[7] = "something"
x[3] = y (where y[1] = "blah")
```

Comment: What's about 0th array element?

Comment: It's not technically an array unless it starts at zero.

Comment: The json field key defines the index of the element. Will update example to make that clear.

Comment: @Hassan The starting index is not relevant. Some languages start at 1, and others allow any arbitrary integer value (ick!)

Comment: @Hassan—an array is an object, it needn't have any numeric members at all.

Comment: @zerkms Uh, *what*? (Perhaps my idea of "sparse" is different...)

Comment: @RobG: don't know why, but I thought that "for years" :-S And always used objects instead of "sparse" arrays...

Comment: Okay you guys. Javascript is weird like that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to deserialize the JSON into a non-array object graph, and then copy the properties into arrays. I'm not aware of any shortcut for it.

The basic loop once you've deserialized the JSON into `obj` is roughly:

```
var ar;
var key;

ar = [];
for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        ar[key] = obj[key];
    }
}
```

...except you'll have to detect that `obj[key]` is an object and recurse, which I'll leave as an exercise for the reader.

---

Note that in JavaScript, [arrays aren't really arrays](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html). Depending on your use-case, you may not need to do the conversion from object to `Array` at all.

Comment: Although except for something wanting the `length` (or other [[prototype]] member) or doing a silly type-check...

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that in Javascript, you can access this:

```
x = {
  "1" : "a",
  "7" : "something",
  "3" : {
      "1" : "blah"
  }
}
```

Like this:

```
alert( x["1"] );
```

which should alert "a". As people already mentioned in the comments above, an array in JS is an "object" already, and there isn't a difference between accessing them these two different ways.

Edit:

Yeah I just tested it and it works. Also, I tried this:

```
alert( x[1] );
```

That is, I tried it with the "number" 1, not the "string" "1". It still worked. Yes it's a very strange programming language.

Comment: There is a problem with large numbers, for example twitter ids `760941020008375486468`, in this case it doesn't work unless a letter is added in front of the number.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is pretty close:

```
function parse_obj(obj)
{
    var array = [];
    var prop;
    for (prop in obj)
    {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
        {
            var key = parseInt(prop, 10);
            var value = obj[prop];
            if (typeof value === "object")
            {
                value = parse_obj(value);
            }
            array[key] = value;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/shaggyfrog/DFnnm/

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"1":"a","7":"something","3":{"1":"blah"}}');
var keys = Object.keys(obj).sort();

// Make obj look like it's an array by taking the highest value
// key and using it to give obj a length property.
obj.length = parseInt( keys[keys.length] ) + 1;

var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(obj, 0);
```

arr now looks like this:

```
[undefined, "a", undefined, Object, undefined, undefined, undefined, "something"]
```

Ok, so it hasn't turned the 'inner' JSON object into an array, but a quick recursive loop doing the same thing as above should sort that out.